# What's the difference between these two "for ... in" statements?

Tags: python, dictionary

What's the difference between these two codes? The first works, but the second doesn't...

```
total=sum(prices[k]*stock[k] for k in prices)

for k in prices:
      total=sum(prices[k]*stock[k])
```

Comment: Where are you getting `key` from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second example is recreating the total on each iteration of the loop. Instead you must use something like this:

```
total = 0
for k in prices:
    total+=prices[k]*stock[k]
```

This will set the `total` to zero initially, and increment the total for each iteration by the amount `prices[k]*stock[k]`.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, just started learning python yesterday. Actually I did that set to zero in the exercise, but why is it necessary to put that + instead of summing it altogether?

Comment: @RubemCarvalho: In your second example, `sum` is not serving any useful purpose. For example, if you were on iteration `k=5`, your code would calculate the value of `prices[5]*stock[5]`. Let's say that value turned out to be `100`. Then the code takes the `sum` of this arguments you passed it, which in this case would look like `sum(100)`. Of course, the sum of 100 is 100. This value is then assigned to `total`, which replaces the total from the previous iteration. Instead of replacing the total, using `+=` will add it to the existing total.

Comment: Oh, I see. At first I thought it would do the job. Thank you very much!